# Python socket outputing wrong arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to get my python code to work on python 3. In python 2 it worked properly but when i put it in python 3 it recieves the wrong text from the socket. In python 2 it recieved `stop` but in python 3 it recieves `b'stop'`. And i can't find out why.

Mycode:

```
import socket
import sys
import subprocess

HOST = '192.168.176.71'
PORT = 8888

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print('socket created')

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print('Bind Failed, Error Code: ' + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1])
    sys.exit()

print('Socket Bind Success!')


s.listen(10)
print('Socket is now listening')


while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    buf = conn.recv(4096)
    if buf == "stop":
        print("stoping")
        exit()
    print(buf)
s.close()
```

Comment: Why the `while 1`? Also, why call `exit()` in that loop? As it stands, `s.close()` is unreachable.

Comment: because i am adding more if statements that wont close the script.

Comment: Pardon? What do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [str.encode adds a 'b' to the front of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810776/str-encode-adds-a-b-to-the-front-of-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'stop'` is a string and `b'stop'` is a bytes object not a string.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) of python 3 for `recv()` says:

> Receive data from the socket. The return value is a bytes object
>   representing the data received.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) for python 2 `recv()` says:

> The return value is a string representing the data received.

So the behaviour is correct in python 2 you receive a string but in python 3 you receive bytes. So if you want this as a string then you need to decode it.

```py
data = bytes('stop'.encode())
print(data)
print(data.decode())
print(data == 'stop')
print(data.decode() == 'stop')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
b'stop'
stop
False
True
```